# How to add JsonObjects to javax.json.JsonArray Using Loop (dynamically)

Tags: java, json

To Add Objects to a JsonArray, following sample code is given on Oracle.com.

```
JsonArray value = Json.createArrayBuilder()
 .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
     .add("type", "home")
     .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
 .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
     .add("type", "fax")
     .add("number", "646 555-4567"))
 .build();
```

Actually I've a Servlet that would read data from the database and depending on the number of rows retrieved, it would add the data as JsonObject to JsonArray. For that all I could think was using loops to add JsonObject to JsonArray but it doesn't work. Here's what I was doing. Here,

```
//Not working
JsonArray jarr = Json.createArrayBuilder()
    for (int i = 0; i < posts[i]; i++)
    {
        .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("post", posts[i])
            .add("id", ids[i]))
    }
        .build();
```

Its my first time using Java Json APIs. What's the right way to add objects dynamically to JsonArray.

Comment: Well obviously the `for` loop is certainly not an object and you cannot call `build` on it. You would want to call build on `jarr` at the end of the iteration. Also, `i < posts[i]` probably doesn't make any sense.

Comment: posts and ids are String array Containing the Data to be added.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you've posted is not written in Java.

First get the builder:

```
JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
```

then iterate and add objects in the loop:

```
for(...) {
  builder.add(/*values*/);
}
```

finally get the JsonArray:

```
JsonArray arr = builder.build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has saved me hours of frustration: turned out I needed to add the `JsonObject` before `build()`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to finish building your JsonObjectBuilder at the end of each iteration to make it work

```
JsonArrayBuilder jarr = Json.createArrayBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < posts[i]; i++)
{
    jarr.add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
        .add("post", posts[i])
        .add("id", ids[i]).build());
}
    jarr.build();
```

Comment: Your first line desn't compile for me. The first word needs to be JsonArrayBuilder. Then it should be called builder, not jarr.

Comment: The concept is good, but the naming convention is whacked.